# Yocto/bitbake/OpenEmbedded: Best place for build/conf/local.conf's content?

Tags: yocto, openembedded

I'm trying out yocto (2.0, jethro) and I want to build an image starting from `core-image-minimal`. This works fine.

Every website out there mention modifying the file `build/config/local.conf` with (some of) my customization. For example, the target machine (through `MACHINE`) or some global settings (through `EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES`).

I also need to modify some specific packages and the way to do it is to create a custom layer. So far so good.

What I don't understand is how to "save" all my configuration to version control. I want everything I change to be locate in files that I can commit so that anybody else can reproduce the exact same build (or even contribute to that project). Putting almost everything in `build/config/local.conf` goes against that goal; the file is under a "build" directory and so I can't just clone a git repo and start the building...

Is it really the way the yocto project works? Or am I missing a different configuration file where I need to put these settings? I though I could place all these in a custom layer but it does not seem to work...

Any idea or suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general everything in your local.conf that is "your project" should be moved to your own distro configuration (MACHINE, image features, package lists).  Stuff like where DL_DIR is can be moved to a common site.conf if you wish.  Eventually you should end up with a local.conf which just sets DISTRO and some other personal variables.

Answer (score 11):

Thanks Ross, that clarified it!

Here's some notes about my file organization which I couldn't format into a comment to your answer.

Thanks. So all my custom configurations went into `meta-mylayer/conf/distro/mylayer.conf`

Almost all my customization went into a layer `meta-mylayer`, except:

- `DISTRO` which is set in `build/conf/local.conf`. This is how you tell yocto what you want to build.
- `MACHINE` which is also set in `build/conf/local.conf`. The reason is that the same image/distro combination could be built for different machines and thus this can't be hard-coded for every images.
- Layers are manually added to `build/conf/layers.conf`. That's the last bit I wish I could moved to my `DISTRO` or something. For now the folders are git submodules and they are added using `bitbake-layers add-layer`.

Comment: Are you still using this file organization, that is, putting your configuration files such as local.conf in `meta-mylayer`, and then comitting `meta-mylayer` to your VCS? If not, what changes/improvements have you made?