# In yocto (poky) why is the layers config in the build/ folder?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I'm new to yocto. I'm trying to learn how the packages are added, how to create new layers and so on... just poking around. Started by cloning poky and playing around.

To my understanding, the `bblayers.conf` file is critical to the project configuration and what you end up building (what layers and packages go into your final image).

This might be the wrong assumption, but I also have a feeling that the build/ folder is where things you build (bitbake) stay. Images, lots of things needed to build them, a big cache of stuff... You can delete it and rebuild it if you somehow broke it. Or you can just copy everything without the build/ folder and continue working on a different computer.

Apparently it's not quite the case. The `build/conf/` folder has the important `.conf` files like the `bblayers.conf`.

Can someone explain why is this the case? Is there an elegant way to separate the project config and the build folder?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34300532/yocto-bitbake-openembedded-best-place-for-build-conf-local-confs-content which is a closely related question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple layers to the Yocto Project, mainly:

-`BSPDIR`: `TOPDIR` (build),sources,setup-environment 
-`BSPDIR/setup-environment`: initial all the variable to for bitbake;
-`BSPDIR/sources`: meta-data/ 
-`TOPDIR`: conf/  sstate-cache/ cache/ tmp/ downloads/ 
-`TOPDIR/downloads`: recipe fetched packages;

-`TOPDIR/conf/` : stored all the configuration. Mainly bblayers.conf, local.conf, sanity_info;
-`TOPDIR/conf/bblayers.conf`: stored all the path to meta-data that will be loaded; 
-`TOPDIR/conf/local.conf`: configuration to build 
-`TOPDIR/conf/sanity_info`: path double check to make sure that all the path used in the last compile match the current compile; 
-`TOPDIR/tmp/`: Where all the compiling and building work happen

In `BSPDIR/sources/poky/meta/conf/bitbake.conf`

```
sources/poky/meta/conf/bitbake.conf:TMPDIR ?= "${TOPDIR}/tmp"
sources/poky/meta/conf/bitbake.conf:PERSISTENT_DIR = "${TOPDIR}/cache"
sources/poky/meta/conf/bitbake.conf:DL_DIR ?= "${TOPDIR}/downloads"
sources/poky/meta/conf/bitbake.conf:SSTATE_DIR ?= "${TOPDIR}/sstate-cache"
```

`TOPDIR` is where you initialize when run `setup-environment` or `oe-init-build-env`; All the other bitbake configuration environment variable can be changed based on your need in `conf/local.conf`;

e.g. modify `conf/local.conf` to change the downloads directory from `TOPDIR/downloads`;

```
DL_DIR ?= "/home/downloads/"
```

To create new layer, please watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HsaoVqX7dg

Comment: So it looks like the important thing in the `TOPDIR` is the `conf` directory (that I can't change) and I can configure the rest to be somewhere else? So it would be perfectly sensible to have a folder called `build` to contain `tmp, downloads, cache, sstate-cache` and a different one called `project` (or something else) that contains the `conf` folder? Will I then be able to just delete my `build` folder and regenerate it from `project` - and it gives me the advantage of clearly separating my config files from the tmp,cache,binaries etc?

Comment: You are correct. Your `project` will be topdir and contains `conf`.  Then in local.conf, set the path for TMPDIR, PERSISTENT_DIR,  DL_DIR, and SSTATE_DIR to path/to/build/ .  Most of the time we only delete the TMP folder instead of everything because the cache and download will make compiling faster for next time.

Comment: It seems to work keeping `conf` in `project`, but I have to remove `build/conf` after each `source oe-init-build-env`. I've copied `oe-init-build-env` into my project root, and modified it so that it does not call `os-setup-builddir`, just creates directory `BUILDDIR`

Answer (score 0):

You might have followed the [Yocto Project Quick Start Guide](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/yocto-project-qs/yocto-project-qs.html).

The earliest step in yocto after installing (cloning git repositories and installing packages) is to create your OE (OpenEmbedded) environment, which is done via:

```
source oe-init-build-env
```

This automatically creates and leads you to the build folder.
Matter that you can give any directory of your system as parameter for this call ([Reference Manual - Build Overview](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#build-overview)):

```
source oe-init-build-env [build_dir]
```

⤑ This is also the step, where your 'project config' is separated from the actual build folder.

⤑ As you assumed, in practice you would at most copy the layers and not the build folder. Even better is to leave sources from others in their git repositories and only copy and maintain your own layers.

Comment: I'm more interested in why is the config generated into the build dir? I would except the `build/` folder (or any `build_dir` given) to be perishable (I can delete and regenerate without losing anything important), except for the `conf` folder within it. I don't get why is this the case (`conf/` inside `build/`)?

Comment: @VladV That's why you should `local.conf` as less as possible and rather set those settings in a custom  `machine.conf` for example. Then you have to set only the machine variable in local.conf and the used layers in bblayers.conf

Answer (score 0):

it is true an issue in the modern **Yocto** build system.

file **bblayers.conf** has to be synthesized based on **MACHINE** and **DISTRO** information using all provided (usually with the help of **repo** manifest file) layers by: collecting data from each available layer file **layer.conf** as well as **conf/machine**, **conf/distro**, **images**.

Instead **bblayers.conf** is usually copied over from the base layer **conf/bblayers.conf** location with the help of **setup-environment** script.

this approach provides no "one click" buildable environment but require maintainer/developer to look into **readme** to identify what layers are missing to be added to the **build/conf/bblayers.conf**.